# python evaluate bool within a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, boolean, list-comprehension

Can I evaluate a bool within a list comprehension?

I would like to create a list that does not contain items that end with `'.zip'`:

```
outlist = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if x *DOES NOT* end with '.zip']
```

I've used list comprehension for the exact opposite:

```
outlist2 = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if x.endswith('.zip')]
```

here is the outout of my list

```
os.listdir(path):
[
'sample1.zip', 'sample2.zip', 'sample3.zip', 'sample4.zip',
'sample1.txt', 'sample2.pdf', 'sample3.csv', 'sample4.xlsx'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `not`:

```
outlist2 = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if not x.endswith('.zip')]
```

The `if` expression can be any valid Python expression, including one that uses boolean operators.

Demo:

```
>>> sample = ['sample1.zip', 'sample2.zip', 'sample3.zip', 'sample4.zip',
...           'sample1.txt', 'sample2.pdf', 'sample3.csv', 'sample4.xlsx']
>>> [x for x in sample if not x.endswith('.zip')]
['sample1.txt', 'sample2.pdf', 'sample3.csv', 'sample4.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can - just slap a `not` operator in there:

```
outlist2 = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if not x.endswith('.zip')]
```